# bing map does not update the bound shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, bing-maps

I have a window defined in XAML that has a bing map element. Without copying the whole window, the relevant part of the XAML is

```
<m:Map x:Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="BLABLA" Mode="Road">
    <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Devices, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <m:MapPolyline Locations="{Binding Locations, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               Fill="Green" Stroke="Blue"
                               StrokeThickness="4" Opacity="1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </m:MapItemsControl>
</m:Map>
```

`Devices` is an `ObservableCollection<PushPinSet>`, where `PushPinSet` is defined has follows

```
public class PushPinSet
{
    public DateTime LastSeen { get; set; }

    public LocationCollection Locations { get; set; }
}
```

When I create the `ObservableCollection` `Devices` (almost) everything is fine: the MapPolylines are drawn accordingly to the `LocationCollection`. I say almost, because for some unknown reason it always skips the first item. I work around it by adding a fake item at the beginning of the collection.
When I try to create a new `LocationCollection` in one of the items of devices in order to deform the shape, the corresponding `MapPolyline` is not updated.

So I have two questions:

1. Do you see any bug in my XAML that justifies the fact that the first item is not displayed?
2. Why are MapPolylines not updated? I am thinking that for some reason when I add/remove items to `Devices` I emit correctly the PropertyChanged event, but the same does not happen when I edit the specific item. If this is correct what and how should I signal, so that the UI works as expected?

**UPDATE**

By following the suggestion of mm8 I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it works a little bit more: the shape does not change, but i can see it change if I zoom out and in or I drag the map. Can I automatically force a redraw of the shapes? I also removed `Mode=TwoWay`, since it was not necessary.
I checked with a bunch of writelines, the collection's count is always n+1, where n is the number of items I want to add and the +1 is due to the fake item.

Comment: If you are setting the `Locations` property to a new `LocationCollection`, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `PushPinSet` and raise the `PropertyChanged` in the setter for the UI to update. And what's the `Count` before and after you are adding the fake item? Are you sure that all items are in the collection initially?

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on both the ItemsSource and the Locations Binding is pointless. Both bindings are inherently OneWay.